# Why did my database update multiple times without errors, but now has errors?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, data-migration

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First and Data Migrations to build my database.

This morning, in the last 2 hours, I've used `update-database` at least 3 times to update the database from the latest Migration.

I made another small change to the data model and attempted another update, only this time, I got the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.BaseRoles'.

I haven't actually opened the POCO class for this table in months so I can only assume that this table name has been in use through the previous updates.

Adding this Data Annotation to the class resolved the problem.

```
[Table("Roles")]
public class Roles : BaseRoles
```

Why has it become necessary to do this **now** when it wasn't necessary 3 updates ago?

Comment: What was the breaking change you made?

Comment: I don't actually know. I was working on Views and Controllers for entirely different tables

Comment: Is your `BaseRoles` class marked as abstract? Sounds like it could be an inheritance issue confusing EF.

Comment: It isn't. It's just a class that defines the Id column for the table.